# Jquery Mobile $.mobile.silentScroll

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

How can I use jquery mobile's silent scroll to force a div to scroll to the bottom? I know how to do this with ScrollTop in jquery but that doesn't seem to be working in jquery mobile.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

With silent scroll method you can scroll the page, not an element.

```
   //scroll to Y 100px          
    $.mobile.silentScroll(100);
```

So, if you want to scroll the page relative to a DIV you should get the position of your div, something like:

```
   $.mobile.silentScroll($('DIV').offset().top);
```